# How can I get <a> objects inside <div> when using puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer

Using puppeteer, I tried getting two  objects in  but failed.
My test code is like this

```
const btnUp = await page.$('div#ember322 > a:nth-child(0)');
const btnDown = await page.$('div#ember322 > a:nth-child(1)');
```

How can I solve this problem?
This is my example codes for the test.

```
<div id="ember322" class="ember-view">
  <div class="order-btn-group">
    <div class="order-value"><span>0.8</span></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <a class="btn-order btn-down txt-left" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-323="323">
          <span class="btn-order-text">down</span>
          <span class="btn-order-value txt-center">
            <small>300</small>
          </span>
          <i class="btn-order-status"></i>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <a class="btn-order btn-up txt-right" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-324="324">
          <span class="btn-order-text">up</span>
          <span class="btn-order-value txt-center">
            <small>500</small>
          </span>
          <i class="btn-order-status"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the selectors without the `>`. It would require the `<a>` elements to be direct children of the `<div>` (see for example [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp)). Like so:

```
const btnUp = await page.$('div#ember322 a:nth-child(0)');
const btnDown = await page.$('div#ember322 a:nth-child(1)');
```

And, maybe instead of using `nth-child`, why not try the `btn-up` and `btn-down` classes?

Comment: I'm all for that `page.$('btn-down')`/`page.$('btn-up')`